# How can I customise the link in a Cognito verification email?

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, email, amazon-cognito

When a user registers via my application, Cognito sends an email with a verification link.

AWS Cognito provides a template (`{## text ##}`) that will transform to some form of link e.g. `<a href='link-to-confirm'> text </a>`.

How can I add CSS styles to this `a` tag?

Comment: Why retract the accepted answer? You need in-line style, but Lambda is an overkill, is it?

Comment: No, in-line style not working for this, because cognito automatically insert link instead of placeholder.  And i don't know how add styles with lambda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `<style>` tag inside a `<head>` section. For example,

```
<head>
  <style>
    a {color : orange !important;}
    a:hover {color : red !important;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="www.google.com">Test link</a>
  {##Cognito link##} 
</body>
```

I tried this myself, and in Gmail at least it works. It will also turn red when I hover over, just that I cannot screenshot it.

[image]

Just a final disclaimer, from what I know, email styling is best done inline (like `<a style="...">...</a>`). So depending on the email client, maybe this approach may not be supported. At least, I've tested this works in Gmail, though.

If you really need to use inline CSS, you can still achieve it by completely customizing the email using Cognito trigger to call a Lambda function. See this [article](https://medium.com/@hasnat_33856/customize-your-cognito-verification-emails-with-html-pages-using-lambda-function-e6fff7ebfb94) for an example. I did not jump to this solution because this is mainly intended for when you need dynamic email content.

Answer (score 1):

AWS Cognito has a set of editable message templates, which also include the verification message template.

To customise the verification message:

1. Navigate to the AWS Cognito service in the AWS console and click on your user pool name.

[image]

2. Scroll down & select the **Messaging** tab.

[image]

3. Under **Message Templates**, select the **Verification message** entry in the table and click **Edit**.

[image]

4. Regardless of your verification type, whether link or code, add any CSS style you like inline & press **Save changes**. Please note that you, unfortunately, cannot modify the `a` tag generated by AWS Cognito itself.

---

Example for **code verification type**:

```html
Your verification code is <span style="color: red;">{####}</span>.
```

Example for email verification type:

```html
Please click the link below to verify your email address.<span style="color: red;">{##Verify Email##}</span>
```

---

[image]

That should save your customised Cognito confirmation code/link.

Comment: but it will be add `a` tag into the span. how can i add css to this a tag. for example how can i disable a hover behavior?

Comment: Try using `pointer-events: none;` - does that work? You can't change the underlying `a` tag unfortunately.